# Single Word Request - An object that makes you happy

Tags: single-word-requests

Cubes are some of my favorites things! 
Cubes are a(n) ____ of mine!

I'm trying to avoid words with negative connotations such as "weakness' or "indulgence" and I'm thinking that words more relating to materialism might fit the bill.

Thanks in advance! I have a fascination with words and I love writing poetry so I'm always looking for fun/interesting words!

Comment: Cubes are [eudaemonic](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/eudaemonic?s=t). Unfortunately you can't say 'they're a eudaemonia of mine.' But the word has got  good spirits and happines in the etymology  -- trust the Greeks --  so I thought I'd throw it into the mix.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific "best" word, or any word that would fit the bill?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest "joy"

> 2. A source or an object of joy: their only child, their pride and joy.
>     [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/joy)

It's hard to understand what you mean by cubes are some of your favourite things, ie., dice, Rubik's cubes, cubic geometrical shapes, etc. Either way I've suggested the word "joy" because the question title asks for a word meaning something that makes you happy, and not only is joy a synonym of happiness, but objects of joy bring happiness.

> joy
>  noun
>  1. A feeling of great pleasure and happiness.
>  ‘tears
>   of joy’
>   1.1 (count noun) A thing that causes joy. 
> [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/joy)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure which of these best fits your needs, but there are several words which have meanings similar to, or the same as what I think you want.
As a number of these have the same dictionary definition, I've grouped them by their meaning. I'm sure there are more, but these are the ones I found fairly quickly.

Definitions taken from [OneLook](https://onelook.com).

**pastime**:

> a diversion that occupies one's time and thoughts (usually pleasantly)

**pleasure**, **delight**, **joy**:

> something or someone that provides pleasure; a source of happiness

**entertainment**, **amusement**:

> a diversion that holds the attention

**inclination**:

> that toward which you are inclined to feel a liking

Comment: OneLook is not a dictionary; it is a search tool.   [Like Google](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2374/26083 "Google is not General Reference") and other search engines, it is not a reference.   Please identify the dictionaries that contain the definitions you quote.

Comment: I used OneLook's "[reverse dictionary](https://onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml)" feature. I then clicked on each of these words and copied the definitions posted in my answer from the box (see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev0KZ.png) for reference) that appeared. I took these definitions from OneLook; where they got them from, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Cubes are some of my favorite things! Cubes are a fascination of mine!

Possibly less awkward a construction might be:

Cubes are some of my favorite things—they fascinate me!
Cubes are some of my favorite things, because they enthrall, tickle, and entice my curiosity (intrigue, interest...)!

Here are a few published examples of *fascination* used this way:

- Puzzles are a fascination of mine.
  [- InfoWorld](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=EDAEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=%22are%20a%20fascination%20of%20mine%22&source=bl&ots=J9s8DAtOx3&sig=OX6pb19p1rDtEUo2AEnK5RFiIhA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZssjk78XcAhXFWrwKHZkkChUQ6AEwB3oECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22are%20a%20fascination%20of%20mine%22&f=false)
- Time travel, as a science, has always been a fascination of mine.
  [- Kyle Lam, The Theory of Everything](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=KoTxCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT69&dq=%22a%20fascination%20of%20mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNp7u58MXcAhVGTLwKHZMaAm4Q6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22a%20fascination%20of%20mine%22&f=false)
- Language is a fascination of mine.
  [- Christine Breakey, The Autism Spectrum and Further Education](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=iZjGDJCPKgoC&pg=PA9&dq=%22a%20fascination%20of%20mine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNp7u58MXcAhVGTLwKHZMaAm4Q6AEIVTAI#v=onepage&q=%22a%20fascination%20of%20mine%22&f=false)

So many ways to express their allure. Have fun!

Comment: +1 I like your answer. On Stack Exchange, answers are intended to be authoritative. As the question is one of usage, I've cited and linked to a few published examples for you.

Comment: Oh, thanks, Lawrence! I am brand new on here, so good to remember that. One question, though, is that if the OP is expected to research the question before asking, wouldn't that also be an expectation if he or she asks for word suggestions, which are easily available with a click? I was thinking that links / references would be required more so in the case of a recommendation that might be obscure, ambiguous, or unclear due to the point of view of the one answering. I'd be grateful for more information on this. Thanks again!

Comment: In a way, yes. For these sorts of questions, though, thinking of the word in the first place is where the intelligent input comes in. Demonstrating that the chosen term is idiomatic can be tricky. Have a look at the answers on this page from the eyes of a later visitor who was googling the topic. Which answer would give them the most confidence to use the expression in, say, a speech? I’d say yours stands above the rest - it *is* idiomatic (that’s important in its own right), and the published examples clinch the deal.

Comment: The more unusual the term, the more important it is to provide support. But if it’s worth answering at all, it’s probably worth answering well. Welcome to EL&U!

Comment: Aha! Very good, thank you for elaborating. I will include links in future responses. I never considered the scenario of future searches, which makes the responsibility for thinking and answering with clarity, transparency and good scholarship even greater. Thank you for the compliment, too. Cheers! S

Answer (score 1):

> Cubes are an **interest** of mine!

From Wiktionary:

[*interest*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interest) (noun) definition 2: (uncountable) A great attention and concern from someone or something; intellectual curiosity. [from later 18th c.]

> He has a lot of interest in vintage cars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking ***delight*** could be the way to go.  From the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[delight](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/delight)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. Great pleasure.
>
>    *‘the little girls squealed with delight’*
>    *‘we broke into an impromptu dance, to the delight of the crowd’*
>    *‘she took great delight in telling your story’*
>
>    1.1  *[count noun]* A cause or source of great pleasure.
>
>    *‘the trees here are a delight’*

Definition 1.1 seems to fit perfectly.  I would state it thusly:

*Cubes are some of my favorites things! Cubes are a **delight** to me!*

Answer (score -1):

a **fave**   Informal  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fave)

> One that is preferred above others or likely to win; a favorite.

As in:

> Cubes are my **faves**!

Comment: Please don't just nominate words and then link to copied text. You still have to write your own answer, in your own words, with an explanation of why you think this is a suitable answer to the request. We're trying to build up a library of expert answers for future visitors, and that requires original content not just dictionary spam. Otherwise we're just somebody else’s thesaurus with voting added.